# The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid

Tags: wcf, reporting, rdlc

I'm installing a service on a machine that will call a method from another WCF service and email a rdlc report.  I have the report being copied to the compile directory and I reference it so it seems to be finding it.

```
            LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

            report.ReportPath = 
                @"C:\Services\Experience Field Manager\ExperienceService\bin\Debug\DailyLog.rdlc";
```

I don't have anything called 'Main Report' in my code.  Any suggestions?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:  Needed to place Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel into the bin/Debug directory of the installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when was porting my application from VS 2008  to VS 2010. There's no need to place Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel into the bin/Debug directory. I needed to install the redistributing ReportViewer files.

Complete path is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago, and i battled with it for several hours
This can be solved by reinstalling the appropriate redistributable file for your application.